# Elasticsearch alpine docker with jdk8 java.time.Instant causes epochSecond error

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have recently tried 2.4.6-alpine with a change from `java.util.Date` to JDK 8 `java.time.Instant`

The Log document is using spring-boot auto injection.

```
import java.time.Instant;

@Document(indexName = "log")
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
    private Instant timestamp = null;
...
```

The previous Log document looked like this.

```
import java.util.Date;
@Document(indexName = "log")
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
    private Date timestamp = null;
```

On ES 2.4.6-alpine with `java.util.Date` and ES 2.4.6 with `java.time.Instant`, I don't have any problems.

However, on ES 2.4.6-alpine with `java.time.Instant`, I see the following error.
It appears to be an issue with alpine linux and java.time formatting.

```
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is MapperParsingException[failed to parse [timestamp]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[unknown property [epochSecond]];] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown property [epochSecond]
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:520)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:241)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:311)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:328)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:254)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:124)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:533)
      at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:510)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:214)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:157)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
      at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
      at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
      at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:378)
      at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any advice to use java.time.* with alpine elasticsearch?

After `docker-compose up -d` command, when I do `curl -xGET localhost:9200/*`
I see there is some initial data.  This data comes back even after `-XDELETE` and `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` commands.

The initial data from the both the elasticsearch:2.4.6 and elasticsearch:2.4.6-alpine dockers is the same.

```
{
  "log":{
    "aliases":{},
    "mappings":{
      "log":{
        "properties":{
          "timestamp":{
            "type":"date",
            "store":true,
            "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "settings":{
       "index":{
         "refresh_interval":"1s",
         "number_of_shards":"5",
         "creation_date":"1513716676662",
         "store":{
           "type":"fs"
         },
         "number_of_replicas":"1",
         "uuid":"qlj9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxoisA",
         "version":{
           "created":"2040699"
         }
       }
     },
     "warmers":{}
   }
 }
```

Ahh.  The initial data is populated during startup of the spring-boot service's auto-injection of the Log document class used in my Elasticsearch implementation.

Found a nice reference to the date-time formats in the javadoc for org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotation.DateFormat class. SOO many time formats with names and none match my output:(

http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: sidenote.  looks like docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1 is a more current elasticsearch.  I'll try switching to that.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally the result of when you submit a document whose format conflicts with a previously indexed document. (like changing the date format from java date to java Instant)

When you change the document format, you will need to clear the corresponding indexes from ElasticSearch.

You can use the [DELETE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-delete.html) API to clear the index (you can use * to clear all like 
`curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/*`), and the [GET](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-get.html) API to verify a clean index. 
(`curl -XGET localhost:9200/*`, or just go to http://localhost:9200/* in your browser. `{}` means you have an empty index)

(This is assuming you didn't also try creating a new ES 2.4.6-alpine to test on. I've seen others using a docker setup with other things where reverting to a 'clean' setup didn't actually get rid of all the old data)

Comment: Thanks.  For each test, I deleted all of the docker containers, networks, volumes, and images. I'll have to try the curl option as well.  My "Date to Instant change on non-apline ES docker" test works.  So, I don't think it's a stale data problem.

Comment: going to try adding `format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` to @Field

Comment: Everything is working now with `curl -XGET` command coming back with "timestamp":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"} now and now error in logs

Answer (score 0):

To get this working with elasticsearch:2.4.6-alpine docker and my spring-boot 1.5.9-RELEASE with auto-injection, I had to add `format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` to the @FIELD annotation.  Apparently, the default 
`org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat.none` does not work with elasticsearch running on alpine.

It must be getting some incompatible time-date format from the alpine 3.7 OS than from the CentOS OS.